# jQuery Multiple Condition in one Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam trying to add Conditions in a variable and then assign in if() condition, but its not working as expected.

Tried Possibilities :

1)

```
conditionCheck = (getMonth == undefined || getMonth == "" || getMonth == null 
     || getDay == undefined || getDay == "" || getDay == null 
     || getYear == undefined || getYear == "" || getYear == null )
```

2)

```
conditionCheck = getMonth == undefined || getMonth == "" || getMonth == null
     || getDay == undefined || getDay == "" || getDay == null 
     || getYear == undefined || getYear == "" || getYear == null
```

3)

```
conditionCheck = "getMonth == undefined || getMonth == "" || getMonth == null 
     || getDay == undefined || getDay == "" || getDay == null 
     || getYear == undefined || getYear == "" || getYear == null"
```

But if i add as is in the condition then its working fine.

like this. - >

```
if ( getMonth == undefined || getMonth == "" || getMonth == null 
       || getDay == undefined || getDay == "" || getDay == null 
       || getYear == undefined || getYear == "" || getYear == null ) {
} else {
  ageCalculation();
}
```

Any Idea / suggestion ?

Edited :

```
function ageCalculation() {
  getDate = getYear + "-" + getMonth + "-" + getDay;
  dob = new Date(getDate);
  today = new Date();
  age = (today - dob) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  if (age < 3 || age == 3 || age > 3 && age < 3.00452422294471007) {
    $('.greater-msg, .less-then-msg').remove();
    $(contentParent).find('.fieldset-wrapper').after('<div class="less-then-msg">Disclaimer: In compliance with EO51,  cannot directly engage with mothers with children aged 0 to 3 years old. All content that you will receive via email will only be regarding your pregnancy. </div>');
  } else if (age > 3) {
    $('.greater-msg, .less-then-msg').remove();
    $(contentParent).find('.fieldset-wrapper').after('<div class="greater-msg">You can also visit to know how you can keep giving your child the 360 advantage.</div>');
  }
  if (age <= -1 || age <= -0 || age == 0 || age == -0) {
    $('.greater-msg, .less-then-msg').remove();
  }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by didnot work. what did you do with conditionCheck variable

Comment: you have no body for your `if`.
Also the 3rd one is just a string which will evaluate to `true`.

Comment: its good to add variablesadd string or num according to data type..  variablesare not for Check of Conditions .. though if you want add let before your variables

Comment: What does `ageCalculation` do?

Comment: @choz, its a function which calculate age on selection of DATE

Comment: Ofc it does. What do you mean by the condition variable did not work?

Comment: @digglemister, please check updated question

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR;** In JS, to check whether `variable` is neither `null`, `undefined` or `empty` is simply just by,

```
if (variable) {
  // 'variable' is not null, undefined or ''.
}
```

---

Your **first** and **second** condition should work just fine.

> **Be aware**, Date.getMonth() returns 0-based index of the month.
>   And if it just happens that month is
>   `January`, your condition will no longer work since `getMonth` is `0`
>   and will turn your `conditionCheck` to be always `true`.
>
> Because `0 == ""`.

As for your **third** condition, which is a string, will always return `true` when wrapped in `if` condition.

***An alternative way,***

So, you want to run `ageCalculation` function if `getMonth`, `getDay`, and `getYear` are **not** `undefined`, `null` or `empty`.

So, instead of *(Your current code)*

```
if (getMonth == undefined || getMonth == "" || getMonth == null || getDay == undefined || getDay == "" || getDay == null || getYear == undefined || getYear == "" || getYear == null) {
   // ...
} else {
   ageCalculation();
}
```

As I state above, For checking whether variable is either `undefined` or `null` or even `""`*(empty)*, you can modify your code to,

```
if (getMonth && getDay && getYear) {
   // getMonth, getDay, and getYear are not null, undefined or "".
   ageCalculation();
}
else {
   // Either getMonth, getDay and getYear have a value of null, undefined or "".
}
```

Comment: You are suppose to answer _"WHY"_ ? Also mention why did you prefer `&&` over `||
`

Comment: @Rayon I don't quite get his `3rd` condition. So I'll just give my suggestion for now..

Comment: @Rayon It's not that I prefer `&&` over `||`, but that's how the reverse logic works.

Comment: there could be many solutions but you are suppose to give reason of _"not working"_ and justification of using other approach than what OP had adapted..

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS Ternary Operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

```
var getMonth;
var getDay;
var getYear;

var conditionCheck = (getMonth == undefined || getMonth == "" || getMonth == null || getDay == undefined || getDay == "" || getDay == null || getYear == undefined || getYear == "" || getYear == null) ? "Hello World" : "Hello Universe!"

console.log(conditionCheck) // Hello World
```

Answer (score 1):

if( myVariable ) {

**//If myVariable's value is not:
   null OR empty string (“”) OR undefined OR NaN OR false OR 0**

} else {

**//If myVariable's value is equal to 
   null OR empty string (“”) OR undefined OR NaN OR false OR 0**

}

So, Ternary Operator can be as :

var getMonth;

var getDay;

var getYear;

var conditionCheck = (getMonth || getDay || getYear) ? '1':'0';

console.log(conditionCheck); // displays 1 if either getMonth, getDay, getYear have values other than null OR empty string (“”) OR undefined OR NaN OR false OR 0